# From where Launch Screen Images Shows on iOS Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In side my project I have LaunchScreen.storyboard file where I create a Launch screen and also I keep the launch screen images Inside AssetCatelog>LaunchImages

so from where my launch screen showing?
and also Unable to set the position of my App Logo center inside LaunchScreen.storyboard
while changing the device the logo automatically changes to another devices

Here is two sample
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hope it helps. refer this link, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens?tabs=windows

Answer (score 1):

I guess the constraints to the logo image within the launch storyboard are missing.

You will have to add the center vertically and horizontally constraints as in the gif below.

You might also need to add the width and height constraints.

[image]

You can check this tutorials on autolayout

[enter link description here](https://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/)